# FINDING VENDORS WITH MATCHING EMPLOYEE ADDRESS: ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, match, vendor

I made this to find vendors that have a matching address as our employees based on the digits in their address and zipcode fields, however it's really slow.  The query strips out any text and joins the digits from the employee table to the vendor tables.

Any way to improve the queries performance?

```
SELECT 
  T1.EMPLID, T1.NAME, T1.ADDRESS1, T1.ADDRESS2, T1.ADDRESS3, T1.ADDRESS4, T1.CITY, 
  T2.VENDOR_ID, T3.NAME1, T2.ADDRESS1, T2.ADDRESS2, T2.ADDRESS3, T2.ADDRESS4, T2.CITY
FROM PS_PERSONAL_DATA T1
JOIN PS_VENDOR_ADDR T2
ON 
  TRANSLATE(T1.ADDRESS1, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-#./ ,',' ') ||
  TRANSLATE(T1.ADDRESS2, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-#./ ,',' ') ||
  SUBSTR(T2.POSTAL,0,5) =
  TRANSLATE(T2.ADDRESS1, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-#./ ,',' ') ||
  TRANSLATE(T2.ADDRESS2, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-#./ ,',' ') ||
  SUBSTR(T2.POSTAL,0,5)
JOIN PS_VENDOR T3
ON T2.VENDOR_ID = T3.VENDOR_ID
WHERE T1.EMPLID <> T2.VENDOR_ID
AND  
TRANSLATE(T1.ADDRESS1, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-#./ ,',' ') ||
TRANSLATE(T1.ADDRESS2, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-#./ ,',' ') ||
SUBSTR(T2.POSTAL,0,5) NOT LIKE ' '
AND T2.VENDOR_ID IN
(
  SELECT VENDOR_ID
  FROM PS_VOUCHER
  WHERE PROCESS_INSTANCE <> 0
  AND POST_STATUS_AP LIKE 'P'
  AND VENDOR_ID NOT IN
  (
  '0000003730',
  '0000003318',
  '0000003555',
  '0000002422',
  '0000003458',
  '0000001089',
  '0000001450',
  '0000003809',
  '0000003255',
  '0000001903'
  )
  HAVING SUM(GROSS_AMT) > 5000 AND COUNT(VENDOR_ID) > 2
  GROUP BY VENDOR_ID
)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the following approach:
-de-normalizing the table by adding two calculated columns, with the results of your formatting
-adding non-primary indexes on those columns

Then you can have a join on those columns that would run a lot faster.

Comment: I only have select access... :(  i can't create/update/delete tables.  thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

- My zipcode was using the wrong table (T2 instead of T1)
- I moved the Vendor_ID criteria outside of the subquery

It now executes in less than 8 seconds.

```
SELECT 
T1.EMPLID, T1.NAME, T1.ADDRESS1 AS EE_ADDR, T2.ADDRESS1 AS VEN_ADDR, T1.ADDRESS2, T1.ADDRESS3, T1.CITY, T1.POSTAL,
T2.VENDOR_ID, T2.ADDRESS1, T2.ADDRESS2, T2.ADDRESS3, T2.CITY, T2.POSTAL
FROM PS_PERSONAL_DATA T1
JOIN PS_VENDOR_ADDR T2
ON 
TRANSLATE(T1.ADDRESS1, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-#./ ,',' ') ||
TRANSLATE(T1.ADDRESS2, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-#./ ,',' ') ||
TRANSLATE(T1.ADDRESS3, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-#./ ,',' ') ||
TRANSLATE(T1.ADDRESS4, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-#./ ,',' ') ||
SUBSTR(T1.POSTAL,0,5) =
TRANSLATE(T2.ADDRESS1, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-#./ ,',' ') ||
TRANSLATE(T2.ADDRESS2, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-#./ ,',' ') ||
TRANSLATE(T2.ADDRESS3, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-#./ ,',' ') ||
TRANSLATE(T2.ADDRESS4, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-#./ ,',' ') ||
SUBSTR(T2.POSTAL,0,5)
WHERE 
TRANSLATE(T1.ADDRESS1, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-#./ ,',' ') ||
TRANSLATE(T1.ADDRESS2, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-#./ ,',' ') ||
TRANSLATE(T1.ADDRESS3, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-#./ ,',' ') ||
TRANSLATE(T1.ADDRESS4, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-#./ ,',' ') ||
SUBSTR(T1.POSTAL,0,5) NOT LIKE ' '
AND VENDOR_ID NOT IN
  (
  '0000003730',
  '0000003318',
  '0000003555',
  '0000002422',
  '0000003458',
  '0000001089',
  '0000001450',
  '0000003809',
  '0000003255',
  '0000001903'
  )
AND VENDOR_ID NOT LIKE 'SF%'
AND VENDOR_ID NOT LIKE 'P%'
AND VENDOR_ID NOT LIKE '_______'
AND T2.VENDOR_ID IN
(
  SELECT VENDOR_ID
  FROM PS_VOUCHER
  WHERE PROCESS_INSTANCE  0
  AND POST_STATUS_AP LIKE 'P'
  HAVING SUM(GROSS_AMT) > 5000 AND COUNT(VENDOR_ID) > 2
  GROUP BY VENDOR_ID
)
;
```

Comment: And to think, I spotted the issue almost as soon as I happened on the question... I might have spared you some 40-50 minutes of (painful?) searching if I saw it back when you posted it. :)

Comment: LOL!  Thanks anyway andriy :D